# How can I run several test files with Pytest?

Tags: python, linux, cmd, automated-tests, pytest

I have a pytest project and a want to run tests from TWO python files. The project structure looks like this: at the root of the project there is a "tests" folder, it contains several folders "test_api1", "test_api2", "test_api3", each of them contains conftest.py and a test file.

tests:

- test_api1:
  conftest.py,
  test_api_1
- test_api2:
  conftest.py,
  test_api_2
- test_api3:
  conftest.py,
  test_api_3

Usually I run tests like this

python -m pytest -vs -k tests (if I want to run all tests from tests directory)

or like this

python -m pytest -vs -k test_api1.py (if I want to run a certain test).

But now I want to run tests from TWO certain files test_api1.py and test_api1.py. How can I do that?

Comment: Tests can be run with just `pytest` in your project home if you followed the [naming rules](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add files that you want to run as positional arguments, e.g.:

```bash
python -m pytest -vs tests/test_api1.py tests/test_api2.py
```

NOTE: you need to run pytest without `-k` flag and hence use paths to the files instead of just filenames.